# Details about why an HTTP request has been 403'ed

Tags: rest, http

I'm working on a RESTful API. I have a complex authorization condition: let's say that you can access the API if you have three different conditions (let's call them A, B, and C). When one of the conditions is not met, the server responds 403 Forbidden (or 401 Unauthorized if the user should log in, or 404 Not Found based on security concerns). However, I would also like to give feedback on why the authorization failed, showing different friendly errors depending on what condition failed. I know that 404 has no body (nor I would want to send one) while 401 and 401 should only have authentication schemes to help the user authenticate.

Is there a way to send responses like 403("reason: A") or 403("reason: C")?

Comment: Why can't you add the user friendly message in the response body for the 401/403/404 ? That's how APIs tend to provide details on the error type and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that 404 has no body [...]

You seem to be messing the things up. While responses with [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) must have no response body, there's nothing wrong in sending a response body along with [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4).

> Is there a way to send responses like 403 ("reason: A") or 403 ("reason: C")?

You surely can return details on why the request has been [forbidden](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) (just be careful to not give away too much information that could be exploited by a malicious user).

Have a look at the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807), which defines simple JSON and XML document formats to inform the client about a problem in a HTTP API. It's a great start point for reporting errors in your API and it also defines the `application/problem+json` and `application/problem+xml` media types.

For reference, check the example provided by such RFC:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> Content-Type: application/problem+json
> Content-Language: en
>
> {
>   "type": "https://example.com/probs/out-of-credit",
>   "title": "You do not have enough credit.",
>   "detail": "Your current balance is 30, but that costs 50.",
>   "instance": "/account/12345/msgs/abc",
>   "balance": 30,
>   "accounts": ["/account/12345",
>                "/account/67890"]
> }
> ```

Comment: You're right. My main issue came from the way ASP.NET Core usually creates those responses. I just found out I can create a "generic" HTTP response and set the status code and payload as I wish.For those who may search this in the future, use `StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.<statusCode>, payloadObject)`.